# Can we put different part of data in same topic on kafa?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, cryptocurrency

Setting an websocket on which kafka listeners are to be added we have basically 100 topics and 13 different different parts of same topic, For Example "BOOKX" is one topic and 13 chapters of it so extra topics will be "BOOKX1", "BOOKX2" etc , are present so is there any way to prevent adding 1300 topics ?
I hope question is understandable

Comment: Do you want to put books in Kafka?

Comment: Can you give an example of the content that is put on those topics?

Answer (score 0):

It sound like there's a design issue, if you have that much of a topics in the first place. Try to find a way to reduce this, if you can. Otherwise,

You can use partitions. In Kafka, each topic can have partitions. When you are creating the topic, you can define the number of partitions for the topic.

When you consume these messages, each consumer in a consumer group is assigned for a particular topic partition. This way you can guarantee the order of a given topic partition.

The downside is that if one of the consumer goes down, the consumers are rebalanced, and the topic partition assignments will be changed. But there are ways you can handle that scenario.

So if you want to avoid the 1.3k topics, the way is to use 100 topics with 13 partitions each.

Comment: So when we consume one partition of 13 in one topic will other left partitions will be available to consume and how we will subscribe according to partition? Plus in every second we will update that partition data also through schedulers

Comment: You can use the message ID to explicitly send messages to a certain partition. The messages with the same ID always goes to the same partition. You can subscribe all the consumers to the same topic. The topic partition assignment is handled by Kafka itself. All the consumers are available to consume.

Comment: But we want only one consumer to consume all partition as per consumer requirement because every partition will have unique data as required by front-end, also if you have any such example please provide here thank you

Comment: Then you can assign one consumer per consumer groups. This isn't a platform where others code for your problems, I am just guiding you, or pointing you the direction. Don't expect me to code for you. Thanks.

Comment: I know  i really just want guidance only actually i am not experienced in kafka so i don't know all available use cases that's why i am asking question here what i am looking is not the code actually :) ..

Answer (score 0):

Creating too many topics is not recommended and could be a sign of bad design. Either you are using the wrong tool for your purpose or you are using it the wrong way.

I suppose that you have data categorized as follows

```
books {
   book_1 {
       chapter_1 {..}
       chapter_2 {..}
       chapter_3 {..}
       ...
   }
   ...
}
```

You can have one topic called *books* and then each message in that topic will be a book chapter where the key will be `bookId_chapterNo` and value will be chapter object. Like `book_1_chapter_1`, `book_1_chapter_2` etc.
If you want to consume all chapters of a particular book or a set of books, you can filter them by key like

```
key.startsWith("book_1") || key.startsWith("book_2")
```

In this way, each consumer can drop the messages which it is not interested in.
You might also want to change the partitioning logic based on `bookId` rather than `bookId_chapterNo` so that messages from a certain book go to the same partition and it also enables you to utilize the consumer group facility.

Comment: Hello, yes we will update the data in every  one second though schedulers using spring boot and java not exactly we will use book and chapters, just created an example similar to my use case..

Comment: I want that one user can consume all partitions as per consume requirement

Comment: Then use `consumer.assign()` instead of `consumer.subscribe()`

Comment: Okay i will try this